# JSON to BSON conversion for testing purposes

Tags: testing, reactivemongo

I'm writing a BSONDocumentReader and would like to create a BSONDocument from a JSON string in my test to verify whether it correctly builds the CC.

So far I haven't found an easy way to do so, can anyone provide an example?

Comment: What have you tried? You can easily convert a Play `JsValue` to a `BSONValue` using the ReactiveMongo Play Json

Comment: Well, that's part of the problem. I'm not using play - at least not in the part I'm working on - and I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: So you need to precise your question because "create a BSONDocument from a JSON string" is just that. And please also indicate what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the solution on SO, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34820280/261984)

```
import reactivemongo.play.json._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection._

val googleJs: JsObject = Json.parse(google).as[JsObject]
val googleBson: BSONDocument = BSONFormats.toBSON(googleJs).get.asInstanceOf[BSONDocument]

val maybeAddress = AddressReader read googleBson
maybeAddress shouldBe defined
// ... and so on...
```

Just make sure you have the [play2-reactivemongo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.reactivemongo.play2-reactivemongo) dependency