# MongoDB Scala Driver counterpart to Javascript Object

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-scala

I am trying to create a document with the counterpart to a Javascript Object `Map[String, Any]`. When I try to insert a new Document I'll get this Exception:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Object.

This is my test document description:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId

object ExampleCollection {
  def apply(test: Map[String, Any]): ExampleCollection = new ExampleCollection(new ObjectId(), test)
}

case class ExampleCollection(_id: ObjectId, test: Map[String, Any])
```

This is the Codec Registry:

```
val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[ExampleCollection]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
```

I have written a small Application and pushed it on [github](https://github.com/bastiankemmer/Scala_MongoDB_Codec_Problem/tree/master).

For now, my workaround would be to serialize the `Map[String, Any]` and save it as String.

So, my question would be, what do I have to do to use `Map[String, Any]` as a type for my dynamic object in mongodb? Or can I do something else to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass just Any to mongo, as soon as it does not know what it is and how to serialize/deserialize it.
If it is json, you can try to convert it to `BSONDocument` instead of `Map` with unknown format.

For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818582/how-to-convert-json-string-to-a-bsondocument) case for converting play-json.